# How to update once a day

Tags: php

I want example_homepage.html update once a day , how ?

```
    <?php

$ch = curl_init("http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/oddlyenough");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.html", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$xml = simplexml_load_file('example_homepage.html');
print "<ul>\n";
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item){
  print "<li>$item->title</li>\n";
}
print "</ul>";

?>
```

Do you know what i mean? This page is very slow , so I want example_homepage.html update once a day. But I dont know how to do ?

Comment: you should then add cron job once a day?

Comment: You could check the file’s modification time.

Comment: if you can use cron, then use cron. if you can't, create a text file, where you store, is that date is cached. if not, then when somebody call the page, create the cached file, store the date. if yes, show the cached page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cron tab for this in Linux environment
for more info
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

or you can use third party cron services
like
http://cronless.com/